# Single tab in UITabBar does not contain a UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having a really strange issue. I've written an app with five tabs in a `UITabBar`. When I set the TabBarController's `viewControllers` property, I set it with five `UINavigationControllers`, so that each tab will have a `UINavigationController` within it.

Four of the tabs have it working perfectly. The navigation bar is there when I launch and switch to that tab. However, one of the tabs does not contain the `UINavigationBar` as I expected it to, and I can't understand why, because I initialized it exactly the same way I initialized all the others.

Here's some sample code from the `AppDelegate.m` file of initializing the individual view controllers:

```
    SpotFilterViewController *spotList = [[SpotFilterViewController alloc] init];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:spotList];

    [tabs addObject:navigationController];
    [navigationController release];
    [spotList release];

    MySpotViewController *mySpot = [[MySpotViewController alloc] initWithSpot:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mySpot];

    [tabs addObject:mySpot];
    [navigationController release];
    [mySpot release];
```

Note: navigationController was declared above.

Anyone else run into this problem before? Or anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it be [tabs addObject:navigationController] again instead of mySpot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing this:

```
[tabs addObject:mySpot];
```

instead of this:

```
[tabs addObject:navigationController];
```